# Foundation Button CSS/SASS

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to flatten the default look of Zurb Foundation using SASS/CSS. Currently I'm running into an issue with the buttons. There is a highlight at the top of the buttons (about a pixel in height) which sort of gives the button a standard button look. **I want to get rid of this highlight.** I am using SASS too manage the CSS, but I can't even figure out where that highlight is coming from.

See the button highlight here: 
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/buttons.html

I've tried using the developer tools to track it down in IE and Chrome, but just can't seem to figure it out. Anyone know how to get rid of the highlight at the top of the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just **remove the box-shadow on the top edge** and the highlight is gone.

In SASS/COMPASS: `@include box-shadow(none)` should do the job. Thus the complete solution will be, adding

```
.button {
    @include box-shadow(none)
}
```

to your sass file.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from `box-shadow`. Apply the following:

```
.button {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to you CSS file:

```
.button {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```